# Getting Started with Spock in Java

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I started learning Spock, this is my setup eclipse/Maven/Spock/Java, I ran a sample from online tutorial, but Eclipse shows these compilation errors below. Any idea what I am missing?

```
import spock.lang.*;

class UserServiceImplSpec extends Specification {

UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl(); 

def "Search for existing name must return correct username"()  //1
{
    expect:
    userService.findUsername("Ikkink") == "sam" //3
}
}
```

> - At line 1: Error: Syntax error on token "Search for existing name must return correct username", delete this token
> - At line 3: Syntax error insert ; to complete the statement

Comment: Are you using Groovy or pure Java?  That second error is complaining about a semicolon, which isn't required in Groovy.  The first error also implies that Groovy is not running correctly.

Comment: I am trying to run pure java.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Groovy plugin for Eclipse? You need it for the syntax and autocomplete

It's available [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin)

Comment: I did, wouldn't complain about the import spock statement if I didn't?

Comment: Not necessarily, since Spock is an extra plugin which uses Groovy. Just like JUnit is an extra plugin which uses Java.

Comment: hmm, How would I know if it's installed correctly knowing that I did follow the instructions on the link you provided.?

Comment: Right click your project and check if there are groovy options available. If there are, make sure the groovy nature is enabled!